# Why grails GORM list of params returns all values

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have

```
SomeClass.createCriteria().list(params) {
            some eqs, ge, le 

            projections {
                property('id')
            }
        }
```

and I use params = [max: 0] - result returns all values. Is it bug or 
feature?

I know exists Hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8989 relates to maxResults(0) - returns all values.

My example is the same way

Comment: If you're using a version of Hibernate in which this bug exists, then that's likely the reason. However, you should be performing appropriate validation of the params such that a nonsensical value such as `[max: 0]` doesn't reach your query

Comment: Thanks. I will do